# Casting to Int32 is required while using enum GetName method

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I'm using ASP.NET and getting a small trouble with `Enum`:

```
public enum Lang : byte
{
    en = 0,
    fr = 1
}

Lang value = Lang.en;

string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Lang), value); // "en"
```

it works. since i changed it to:

```
@foreach (SelectListItem lang in Html.GetEnumSelectList<Lang>())
{
    string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Lang), lang.Value);
}
```

i'd got this error message:

> ArgumentException: The value passed in must be an enum base or an underlying type for an enum, such as an Int32.
>    Parameter name: value

then, i'd tried:

```
string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Lang), Convert.ToInt32(lang.Value));
```

it worked.

why's that?

`Lang.en` is a `byte`, why does it require an `Int32`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the documentation for [`Enum.GetName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx), we can read:

> **ArgumentException**:
>   * `enumType` is not an `Enum`
>   OR
>   * `value` is neither of type `enumType` nor does it have the same underlying type as `enumType`

The problem is that in your second approach you are using `Convert.ToInt32(lang.Value)`, hence obtaining an `Int32` instead of a `byte` as your enum requires:

```
public enum Lang : byte
```

So, the simple solution is to pass in a `byte` instead of an `int`:

```
string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Lang), Convert.ToByte(lang.Value));
```